# Using 'broader' community tag for 'specific' problems

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I recently posted this questions :

[Using texture image with alpha makes mesh 'see through'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893742/using-texture-image-with-alpha-makes-mesh-see-through#35893742)

And somebody removed the tag for openGl from it in the edit.

[image]

I understand that OpenGL-ES is a more specific tag, but my intention was to address the larger OpenGL community as well, in case they can find some generic problem in my implementation from a broader Graphics perspective.

Is it a good practice or I should be as specific as possible?

Comment: OpenGL ES is a subset of OpenGL. I'm not an OpenGL expert but it seems that it would be the same as tagging C++ questions with C because C++ is a superset of C.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker That's one of the least well achieved in the c++, c communities.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ehm, what? What is?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker _"it would be the same as tagging C++ questions with C because C++ is a superset of C."_.